# How to use PayPal Payment Buttons JavaScript API?

Tags: javascript, paypal

I'd like to use paypal.button.create from the [JavaScript API](https://github.com/paypal/JavaScriptButtons#javascript-api) of [PayPal Payment Buttons](https://github.com/paypal/JavaScriptButtons). I'm wondering if there is a file on [paypalobjects.com](http://paypalobjects.com) where I can access the API? It doesn't seem to be part of `www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/paypal-button.min.js` or `www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/paypal-button-minicart.min.js`.

Baring that any info on how I can go about using paypal.button.create would be appreciated. I'm a JavaScript newb.

Answer (score 2):

Grab this script from Github:

https://github.com/paypal/JavaScriptButtons/blob/master/dist/button.js
and call it:

```
paypal.button.create(business, data, config, parentNode);
```